# Image rotation issue in picasso

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide

When the image is fetched from API (originally uploaded from iOS device), that time when image is set in android image view using Picasso, it gets auto rotated.

But when I use glide it's set perfectly fine, although this is more time taking. Please suggest which one to use for setting image from URL.

*Note:
The problem is usually faced when image source is iOS, otherwise when image is directly uploaded on server, and fetched on Android, then this works fine.

Comment: Try not using Picasso first, then check the result.

Comment: In which(either landscape or portrait ) mode the image was captured through IOS device?

Comment: I faced the same issue

Comment: Enzokie, I have also used it without Picasso that time also has rotation issue but when I hit that URL on browser image looks correct.

Comment: Ankita, It's portrait mode.

Comment: hello, guys  I am also facing same issue...have you find any solution for this issue?